# Regex, ignore results with preceding character

Tags: php, regex

I have a regex for matching URLs `((https?:\/\/)?[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+\.?(:\d+)?(\/\S*)?)` and it does the job, it works for what I want. However it will also match the domain for an e-mail when I don't want it to.

Currently matchs:

- http://www.foo.bar
- foo.bar
- website: **foo.bar** (matches the foo.bar part)
- info@**foo.bar** (matches the foo.bar part)

I don't want it to match that last one, so it only matches the first three. I tried adding `(?!=@)` to the front but that didn't do it. How can I get it to ignore results preceded with an @ symbol?

Answer (score 2):

Add anchors to your regex

```
^((https?:\/\/)?[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+\.?(:\d+)?(\/\S*)?)$
```

see the example http://regex101.com/r/lI8kZ6/1

**Explantion**

`^` asserts the regex at the start of the line

`$` asserts the regex at the end of the line

**EDIT**

If the urls are embedded within text use `\s` to delemit the regex match strings as

```
(\s|^)((https?:\/\/)?[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+\.?(:\d+)?(\/\S*)?)\s
```

see the example

http://regex101.com/r/lI8kZ6/3

Comment: I do want it to be able to match partial lines though, I've updated the question to include a third example that I need to match. Are there any tags that will match urls (whole words) in a line? I've tried `\b` instead of `^` and `$` but that didn't work.

Comment: check the edit in the answer `\b` cannot be used as `@` is also treated as a word boundary

Answer (score 2):

Anchors will only work if your string *only* consists of the URL you want to match. This is probably not the case.

Instead, what you really want is to match where there is space (or nothing) before the URL. Try:

```
(?:^|(?<=\s))YOUR REGEX HERE
```

This will check if there is nothing, or a space character, before the regex you already have.

[Demo on regex101](http://regex101.com/r/xM6uX0/1)

Consider further adding `(?=\s|$)` to the end of the regex, to ensure it doesn't match half a word.

Answer (score 1):

```
^((https?:\/\/)?[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+\.?(:\d+)?(\/[\S]*)?)$
```

just add anchors to remove partial matching.Enable `m` or `multliline` flag.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/sU3fA2/43

Comment: Thank you, but there is a third situation that I need to match that I've added to the question. Do you know how I could match whole words as part of a string?